# decrypting a variable in a scripting environment of Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

What does `$@` in unix shell script signify. For example:

```
A__JOB="$CLASS $@"
```

where $CLASS has my java class file name. So what might be the meaning of

```
$@.
```

What did I do?
I Googled :) but $@ seems to be complex query for ir or maybe i do not know how to search google for special characters.

Comment: You probably want to *quote* `$@` in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$@` is the value of all arguments passed.

For example, if you pass:

```
./script A B C D
```

then "$@" will be equal to `"A" "B" "C" "D"`

So it looks like the purpose is to passe all the arguments passed to the script directly to the java program.

From bash manual:

> @      Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When
>   the expansion  occurs  within  double  quotes,  each  parameter
>             expands  to  a  separate  word.   That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...  If the double-quoted expansion occurs
>   within a
>             word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the  expansion  of  the
>             last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word.  When there are no positional parameters, "$@" and $@ expand
>             to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Comment: Correction to your example, as shown in your quote too: `$@` is special, `"$@"` for your case will expand to `"A" "B" "C" "D"`. This is what makes it different from `$*`, which would expand to that `"A B C D"`.